# Jquery: Temporary disable swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to disable swipe, for example on a click event and then enable swipe again? I know you can use stopPropagation, but how do you then enable it again?

Thanks

Comment: Look into binding and unbinding jQuery events.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered partially here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325428/4408994

The recommendation by wot is the correct method.  Instead of stopping the propagation of events, namespace the events you bind so that you can bind/unbind them as you need.

For example, bind like this (to detect swipes):

```
jQuery('body').on('swipeleft.my_event_namespace_name', function(){//code});
```

Then unbind like this (to disable detection of swipes):

```
jQuery('body').off('swipeleft.my_event_namespace_name');
```

You can repeat this binding and unbinding as much as you need.