# How to AJAX-ify a random button on Blogger?

Tags: ajax, button, random, blogger

I'm using a script to use AJAX on my blogger (https://github.com/swook/jquery-ajaxify-plugin) so users can listen music via the music player without interruption while they're navigating through differents pages.

Everything works except the random button. I'd like to AJAX-ify the random button.

The problem is when I click on the link, the page reloads.

You can check the different problems here: http://www.julienlussiez.com/p/test_20.html (There're 3 random buttons with different script)

Test #1: I have this [I tried many things on this code but nothing seems to work]:

```
     <div id="myLuckyPost"><a href="#random" onclick="feelingLucky();return false;" title="Aléatoire">Aléatoire</a></div>
<div id='head'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function showLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var entry = feed.entry[0];
      for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j) {
       if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
       window.location = entry.link[j].href;
       }
      }
   }

function fetchLuck(luck){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }
function readLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
    var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    luckyNumber++;
    fetchLuck(luckyNumber);
    }

function feelingLucky(e){
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    if(e && e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    return false;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Test #2 : With an other script for randomizing articles. The problem is still the same.

```
<script>
<!--
/*
Random link button- By JavaScript Kit (http://javascriptkit.com)
Over 300+ free scripts!
This credit MUST stay intact for use
*/

//specify random links below. You can have as many as you want

var randomlinks=new Array()

randomlinks[0]="http://www.julienlussiez.com/2013/01/le-repos-du-fou_21.html"
randomlinks[1]="http://www.julienlussiez.com/2012/11/dissonance-3.html"
randomlinks[2]="http://www.julienlussiez.com/2012/10/renaitre.html"
randomlinks[3]="http://www.julienlussiez.com/2013/01/defaillance.html"
randomlinks[4]="http://www.julienlussiez.com/2012/08/fragile-2012.html"

function randomlink(){
window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}

//-->
</script>
<form>
<p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Aléatoire" onclick="randomlink(); return false;" /></p> </form>
```

Test #3 : With an other script for randomizing articles. The problem is still the same.

```
<script>
/* Simple Random Posts function for Blogger
 * Copyright 2012 Yu-Jie Lin
 * Licensed under the MIT License
 */
function blogger_random_post(){
  // You can replace the value with your blog ID
  var blogID = $('#blogID').val();
  // for example:
  //  blogID = "4586487713356156869";
  var BLOGGER_POSTS_API = "http://www.julienlussiez.com/feeds/posts/summary";
  // appending necessary parameters
  BLOGGER_POSTS_API += "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=?";
  // replacing blogID with value
  BLOGGER_POSTS_API = BLOGGER_POSTS_API.replace('blogID', blogID.toString());
  $('#btn-blogger-random').text('Tossing dice...');
  // retrieving posts count
  $.getJSON(BLOGGER_POSTS_API, function(data){
    var posts_count = parseInt(data.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t);
    // index is 1-based
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * posts_count) + 1;
    // retrieving post link
    $.getJSON(BLOGGER_POSTS_API + '&start-index=' + index, function(data){
      $.each(data.feed.entry[0].link, function(idx, link){
        if (link.rel == 'alternate')
          // redirecting
          document.location.href = link.href;
      });
    });
  });
}
$(function(){
  $('#btn-blogger-random').click(blogger_random_post);
});
</script>
<label>Blog ID <input id="blogID" value="4586487713356156869"/></label>
<button id="btn-blogger-random">I'm Feeling Lucky &raquo;</button>
```

Thanks! It would be very nice if you'd have some clues!

Comment: Now, you have two `feelingLucky` function! The second one would overwrite the first one!

Comment: Ok, I've just edited the code. Now, I'm back to the beginning. I don't know what I have to change to stop refreshing.

Comment: If you comment the `document.location.href = link.href;` treatment, is it still refreshing? And in your new `blogger_random_post`, I can't see where do you add something into the DOM! Can you show me a Json example of what *post link* is?

Comment: You can check it on the bottom of the article. The page is still refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `stopPropagation`.

For that, you can add `return false;` to the end of the function.

See [How to stop propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735006/javascript-how-to-enable-stoppropagation)

And if it doesn't work, you can add

```
// event is the Event object
if (event.preventDefault) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
event.returnValue = false;
```

See [Alsacreation (in french ^^)](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/578-La-gestion-des-evenements-en-JavaScript.html)

The `event` is an object you must pass to the caller...

```
<div id="myLuckyPost"><a href="#random" onclick="feelingLucky(event)" title="">BD Aléatoire</a></div>

function feelingLucky(event){
  //now you can use event.stopPropagation...

}
```

You also can retrieve this object by using `window.event`, but it's not cross browser! See [Other topic on Javascript Event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849370/get-the-event-object-in-an-event-handling-function-without-pass-the-event-object)

Comment: It doesn't work. The random button keep refreshing the page. Thanks anyway! I'm going to try again...maybe I don't write the code correctly.

Comment: Maybe with `javascript:void(0)` or `javascript:void('something')` in the `<div id="myLuckyPost"><a href="` instead of `#random`

Comment: No...it doesn't work. I've just edited my post to show the code now. Maybe there's a problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Your code works too on Blogger but I just have "Somethink will be added" when I click on the random button. 
What should I change in the code?

Comment: Just replace the Fiddle's feelingLucky function with your's.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your existing `feelingLucky` function to

```
function feelingLucky(e){
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    if(e && e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If it doesn't work, youre problem is in the `'/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky'` page or in the ajaxify.js

**IDEA**

You can try to change your `<a>` to another element like `<span>`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I've tried but it still doesn't work. Yes, maybe the problem is in the '/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky' page or in the ajaxify.js.

Comment: I'm trying an other script (EDIT). I have the same problem but maybe there's a solution on this one. I don't know what to modify.