# I have a page with two sections map at the top and accordion menu at the bottom when i click accordion page is scrolling to top

Tags: jquery

I have a page with two sections map at the top and jQuery accordion menu at the bottom when I click accordion menu page is scrolling to top, I need the page should stay at the same place so I can see the jQuery accordion menu properly.

Is there anyway to prevent this? So that when I click on the menu, the page should stay at the same place in the browser?

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(event,ui){
    /*var ahref = $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
    if(ahref!='#'){
        window.location.href = ahref;
    }else{*/

        var currentlink=$(event.currentTarget);
        if (currentlink.parent().find('ul.active').size()==1)
        {
            currentlink.parent().find('ul.active').slideUp('medium',function(){
               currentlink.parent().find('ul.active').removeClass('active');
            });
        }
        else if (menu.find('ul li ul.active').size()==0)
        {
            show(currentlink);
        }
        else
        {
            menu.find('ul li ul.active').slideUp('medium',function(){
                menu.find('ul li ul').removeClass('active');
                show(currentlink);
            });
        }
   /* }*/
});
```

to scroll accordion menu

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return false` or [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) at the end of your click event function otherwise the browser will follow the `<a href="#">` link you are clicking on by appending `#` to the page URI which instructs the browser to find the *named* anchor on the page. Since you are not supplying an anchor name (for example `http://www.url.com/page#` instead of `http://www.url.com/page#anchorname`) the browser jumps to the top of the page.

For example

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(event, ui){
    // your code

    // choose one of the following lines
    return false
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735006/javascript-how-to-enable-stoppropagation), [event.preventDefault or return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)...
Or just change the `href` to `javascript:void(0)`.