# stopPropagation() div inside div onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I want to put a div inside another div, and when the user put the mouse on the parent div the two divs show up.

The problem is that when I put the mouse over the parent div the two divs show up but when I move the mouse over the child div the show() function execute it self again, how can I stop that?

### HTML code:

```
<div id="parent" onmouseover="show(this)">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript code:

```
function show(element) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        opacity(element)
    }, 100);
}

function opacity(element) {
    element.style.opacity = "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can and should be solved using CSS only, without JavaScript.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbe36gdd/)**

```
<div id="parent">
    Parent Text
    <div id="child">Child Text</div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent {
    opacity: .2;
    transition: .1s opacity;
}

#parent:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery :

```
$('#child').hover(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

with normal js :
a simple google search for javascript stopPropagation()

[Javascript : How to enable stopPropagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735006/javascript-how-to-enable-stoppropagation)

Comment: thank you for your reply but I don't want to use jquery.